# installing Heroku-toolbelt in Kali-sana

Tags: heroku, installation, heroku-toolbelt

i am Trying to install heroku tool belt in Kali sana from :wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh  and i keep getting the error below any help?
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 heroku-toolbelt : Depends: heroku (= 3.43.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know this thread is old but I just got heroku working on kali and found this thread while searching.

$ wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-linux-386.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz

$ mkdir -p /usr/local/lib

$ tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib

$ /usr/local/lib/heroku/install

Above is what I used, the 386 part for ARCH as in architecture is 32bit, so you would need amd64 for 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install software-properties-common # debian only

[nano | echo | leafpad ] "deb https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"  """into"""  /etc/apt/source.list

curl -L https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install heroku

Answer (score 0):

apt-get update

wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

heroku update

this would update all the plugins to the latest version of the heroku cli...goodluck